# Random object in array can be picked once

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this function that picks a random color from my colorArray. Then I generate 10 Random colors in `const randomColors`. How can I make sure it doesn't pick the same color twice?

I thought something like `if (randomColors[i] === randomColors[i]) {console.log('Same')}`but I dont think that are the right approch to my problem

````
function getRandomColor() {
  var colorArray = ['#D32F2F', '#FF4081', '#7B1FA2', '#7C4DFF','#303F9F', '#448AFF', '#0288D1', '#00BCD4','#00796B', '#4CAF50', '#689F38', '#AFB42B','#FFEB3B', '#FFA000', '#FF9800', '#E64A19', '#455A64'];
  var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length);
  console.log(colorArray[randomColor])
  return colorArray[randomColor]
}

const randomColors = [
    getRandomColor(),
    getRandomColor(),
    getRandomColor(),
    getRandomColor(),
    getRandomColor(),
    getRandomColor(),
    getRandomColor(),
    getRandomColor(),
    getRandomColor(),
    getRandomColor(),
]; ```
````

Comment: Remove the color from the array each time it's been used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t understand if you want to avoid two consecutive colors, or avoid any repetition.
The first case can be do by saving the last chosen color and removing it from the sellecionables.
In the second case you have to remove the chosen colors from the sellecionables. However, at the end it empties, I have restarted the list.
I do two "classes" for do it.

```js
var colorArray = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow','orange', 'black', 'white'];

var randomColorNoConsecutiveClass = function(colors){
 if (!Array.isArray(colors)) throw  "First parameter of randomColorClass must be a colors array.";
 var lastColor = -1;
 this.get = function(){
  var selecionnableColors = [];
  for (let i = 0 ; i < colors.length ; i++){
   if (i != lastColor) selecionnableColors.push(i);
  }
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*selecionnableColors.length);
  lastColor = selecionnableColors[randomIndex];
  return colors[lastColor];
 }
}
var randomColorNoRepeatClass = function(colors){
 if (!Array.isArray(colors)) throw  "First parameter of randomColorClass must be a colors array.";

 var copyOfArray=[];
 for (let i = 0 ; i < colors.length ; i++ ) copyOfArray.push(colors[i]);

 this.get = function(){
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*copyOfArray.length);
  var color = copyOfArray[randomIndex];
  copyOfArray.splice(randomIndex,1);
  if (copyOfArray.length==0){
   for (let i = 0 ; i < colors.length ; i++ ) copyOfArray.push(colors[i]);
  }
  return color;
 }
}

var randomColor1 = new randomColorNoConsecutiveClass(colorArray);
var randomColor2 = new randomColorNoRepeatClass(colorArray);

const randomColorsNoConsecutive = [
 randomColor1.get(),
 randomColor1.get(),
 randomColor1.get(),
 randomColor1.get(),
 randomColor1.get(),
 randomColor1.get(),
 randomColor1.get(),
 randomColor1.get(),
 randomColor1.get(),
 randomColor1.get(),

];
const randomColorsNoRepeat = [
 randomColor2.get(),
 randomColor2.get(),
 randomColor2.get(),
 randomColor2.get(),
 randomColor2.get(),
 randomColor2.get(),
 randomColor2.get(),
 "Refill...",
 randomColor2.get(),
 randomColor2.get(),
 randomColor2.get(),
 randomColor2.get(),
 randomColor2.get(),
 randomColor2.get(),
 randomColor2.get(),

];
console.log("No consecutive: ",randomColorsNoConsecutive);
console.log("No repeat: ",randomColorsNoRepeat);
```

Edit:
Other easyer method to not repeat two consecutive colors, using that @little_monkey say, are select one randomly of the array, except the last one, and then, move the selected to end of array.
The "problem", is that the last color can't be select the first time you get one.

```js
var colorArray = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow','orange', 'black', 'white'];

var randomColorNoConsecutiveClass = function(colors){
 if (!Array.isArray(colors)) throw  "First parameter of randomColorClass must be a colors array.";
 var copyOfArray=[];
 for (let i = 0 ; i < colors.length ; i++ ) copyOfArray.push(colors[i]);
  
  this.get = function(){
    var lastIndex = copyOfArray.length-1;
    var colorRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*lastIndex);
    var color = copyOfArray[colorRandom];
    copyOfArray.splice(colorRandom,1);
    copyOfArray.push(color);
    return color;
  }
}

var randomColor = new randomColorNoConsecutiveClass(colorArray);

console.log (colorArray[colorArray.length-1]+" never can be the first :(");
const randomColorsNoConsecutive = [
 randomColor.get(),
 randomColor.get(),
 randomColor.get(),
 randomColor.get(),
 randomColor.get(),
 randomColor.get(),
 randomColor.get(),
 randomColor.get(),
 randomColor.get(),
 randomColor.get(),
];

console.log("No consecutive: ",randomColorsNoConsecutive);
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the specified color from the array using by either using `pop()` (removes the last element in an array) , `shift()` (the opposite of pop()) or `splice()` (you can choose which element you want to remove.

More info on them [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_methods.asp).